# How to call jsp page from java method or class

Tags: java, html, jsp

I want to call a `JSP` page through my `JAVA` class or method meaning when I run my `JAVA` program then:

- If condition correct, then open a web jsp page
- If condition incorrect, print something wrong.

I am new in `JAVA` so I'm not able to start writing this type of program. How can i do this?

I tried this code but I am not getting anything from this:

```
   java class

    package Myjava;

    public class Test
    {
     public void printHello()
     {
      System.out.println("Thi Is java class......");
     }
   }

 jsp page

 <%@page import="Myjava.Test" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <%
  if(request.getParameter("submit") != null)
   {
  Test t= new Test();
  t.printHello();
    }
  %>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I have understood correctly what you are trying to achieve, but if I have, you cannot open a jsp page from straight Java code. JSP is designed for web applications, so you would have to put your jsp file inside a project that you can deploy onto a web container, such as Tomcat or Jetty. Then you have to configure the web server properly to allow your java code and jsp code to talk to each other correctly.

If in fact all you are trying to do is open a browser page from inside some Java code and navigate to a URL, you can use a ProcessBuilder or the Runtime.exec() to open a browser to the URL you are thinking of (eg IE, Chrome, Firefox etc)